# Issue while creating index with structured excel file

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, openaiembeddings

I am trying to index the excel file using `langchain` class `UnstructuredExcelLoader`. when user ask the question its picking wrong answer. Though it's giving right answer to some of the questions, however it's not giving any answer to most of the questions.

I created the index to a structured excel file using `UnstructredExcelLoader` from `langchain`.

- Is there any option and way to index the excel file?
- Can any one suggest the way to pick the correct answer from the excel
  file?

When we index the text formatted excel file its giving correct answer. but its not working when excel file is having numerical and formula type of data.

```
 def loadExcelFile(path):
     file = 'excelFileName'
     excel_path = os.path.join(path,file)
     loader = UnstructuredExcelLoader(excel_path)
     documents.extend(loader.load())
     return document
```

the document is sent to the `CharacterTexttextSplitter` from `langchain`.